# How to Factory Reset Device using Adb Command?

Tags: adb, factory-reset

I am trying to do Factory Reset Device without any Recovery as i need to wipe complete data from device. I have tried many Commands but none of them work. Some are as Follows:-

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MASTER_CLEAR
```

This command works with phone contains api level less than 22 but not on Upper Api level Devices.

I also tried --wipe_data command but it says Command not found.

Can anyone tell me how can i Factory Reset Data without Recovery Device.

Thanks

Comment: `--wipe_data` is a flag of `recovery` command. After entering ADB Shell, run `recovery --wipe_data`. May not work if you have custom recovery.

Comment: Without recovery, your phone needs to be rooted. `adb shell  "su -c 'am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MASTER_CLEAR'"`

Comment: @AndroidPopsicle I deleted my answer since I did not know nor I took into account that intent and rooted part and I'm short on time to correct it. Please post an answer incorporating both of your comments.